# Using an Array with table and loop

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I am sorry if this sort of questions has already been asked, I couldn't find the answer I needed and I am quite new to VBA.

I am trying to match some values from one table to the other via an Index Match which is moving between 2 Workbooks. To do this properly I have used two loops For To. But my Code is really slow when it comes to a few thousands lines. Can I improve it with an Array or something else?

```
Dim mainWB  As Workbook
Dim mainWS  As Worksheet
Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set mainWS = mainWB.Sheets(1)

Dim RowsToProcess As Long
RowsToProcess = mainWS.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = mainWS.Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Range(Cells(11, 8), Cells(RowsToProcess, lastCol)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"

For i = 1 To lastCol
    For a = 1 To RowsToProcess
        If Workbooks("template.xls").Sheets("#").Cells(10 + a, 7 + i).Value <> vbNullString Then
            Cells(10 + a, 7 + i).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "= "Long Formula" "
        End If
    Next
Next
```

For my Long formula. It is basically doing 2 Index(Match. between this Workbook and 2 others, but I thought I would take it out here to keep it clearer

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: First thing is that you should get rid of `.Select` this is a very bad practice and always slows down your code. There are many tutorials out there how to avoid using `.Select`. Also look at [Application.ScreenUpdating Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-screenupdating-property-excel) and consider switching to manual calculation mode at the beginning of your code and switch back to automatic in the end, see [Application.Calculation Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-calculation-property-excel).

Comment: Avoid .Select e.g. Cells(10 + a, 7 + i).Select  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1   can be written as  Cells(10 + a, 7 + i).FormulaR1C1. Also, use With Statement when working with Objects e.g. http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm

Comment: Without .select I went down from 166 processing time to 41s and then 26s with manual calculation Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are effectively defining a range you can use the first and last columns and rows addresses and create a range object.
See examples here: [Dynamic ranges](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/5-ways-to-create-a-dynamic-auto-adjusting-vba-range)

You can then do:
Range(myRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "LongFormula"
which effectively replaces all blank cells with your formula without having to do all the loops.

Combine those steps with the items mentioned in the comments such as avoiding .select.

Summary:

Avoid the .select

Use WITH where possible when working with objects

Get the first cell address and last cell address and create your range object

Use the special cells method to set blanks in this range to your formula.

Comment: This helped a lot already, but the .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) didn t work out for me because the sheet is protected. And using Range(myRange).FormulaR1C1 = ... without the SpecialCells ended up even more slow than my 2 loops. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What error message were you getting with the .SpecialCells method?

Comment: Runtime error 1004: You cannot use this command on a protected sheet. [...]

Comment: 1) Do you know the password for the sheet?  2) What are you trying to achieve with the long formula? Is there an example input and expected output you could give?

Comment: No I do not have the password. The formula is getting something from another sheet (index Match match) then translating it through a third sheet (index match match) in case the first word is a word.

Comment: Can you manually type the formula into one of the target cells? I am trying to understand how you would input formulas into a protected sheet if that is the case.

Comment: Yes it works I am also confused. The only thing that changes is the SpecialCells part.